# I need to update an aggregated list that was copied from various sub-sites using work flows if possible

Tags: workflow, updatelistitems

I have a main **list** that has a copy of each list item from several sub-sites.  These sub-sties use a **template list** created so all information fields are the same. I am able to copy each sub-site's items when they are created to the main list. However, if a user from the sub-site changes an item in their list, I would like the same item on the main site to be updated as well.

I used the **"copy list item extended" workflow** to copy items from each sub-site. **"UPDATE"** the item across sub-sites to the main site?

I tried using the **Lookup** feature when creating a list column as well, but that has limitations to fields I need from sub-sites. Are there any solutions out there?

Generally, I need to be able to update the main aggregated list when any sub-site changes their list information.